# See text in cross-frame scripting in IE

Tags: security, internet-explorer, scripting, frame

I know its a security feature in IE to not allow scripts to interact past frame tags/objects but is there a way around this?

I am using a program to interact with the IE COM interface.

For example if I were to have an  tag and I wanted to use the $tagobject.innerhtml to retrieve the html inside the frame tag, what is the best way of going that this?

Comment: I am trying to make a website that will still allow IE to do use scripts on another page using an iframe. What would the application atrribute do?

I a refering to this securty issue http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533028%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Native code running at full trust (e.g. an IE plugin) can interact with any document loaded in the browser. You're correct to note that interacting with subframes that are from an origin different than the top-level page is blocked by security policy when accessed in the "simple" way. But native code can circumvent that.

This [support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196340/en-us) shows how to enumerate the contents of all frames, regardless of their origin. The basic idea is that you cast the top-level document to an `IOleContainer` and then enumerate its children, which bypasses the security check.

Comment: That sounds like what I am looking for but I am note sure about how I could implement it. Would I need the Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.dll